# MySql: LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: permissions, mysql, database

I am using **MySQL v5.1** on **Ubuntu** machine.

**MySQL** data directory is `/var/lib/mysql/`

I have a `test.dat` file located on `/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat`

I would like to load data from the `test.dat` file into my database table, so I execute the following SQL statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat'
            INTO TABLE myapp.cars;
```

But I got the following error:

`Mysql2::Error: Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat' (Errcode: 2): LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat`'

What could be the reason??

**P.S.** one thing come to my mind is that `/var/lib/mysql/` can only be accessed by **root user**, but I am not sure if it is the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ ls -ld /var/lib/mysql
drwx------ 21 mysql mysql 4096 2011-11-18 14:07 /var/lib/mysql
```

Yes, you have no permissions for that directory (it may be `root:root` depending on your setup).  Use:

```
sudo mysql -u mysqluser -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/test.dat' INTO TABLE myapp.cars;"
```

Or just copy the file to your home directory (or wherever) and `chown` it to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if your file is on localhost, use

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...
```

instead of `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Plus, have the file permission to be readable by mysql user,
and plus have this run by mysql root:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* to <your_db_user_name>@localhost;
```